# (Symfony 4) How to implement a constants class

Tags: symfony, constants

I'm trying to have constants everywhere in my code so I don't have to just stick numbers, I know that's bad practice.

So in my root folder I put a class constants, like this:

```
namespace App;

class Constants{

    public const FREE_TIER = 0;

}
```

So I include the  "use App\Constants;" in my repository class.

Here is the function I try to access my constants class in:

```
use App\Constants; /* earlier on */ 

/**
 * @param User $user
 * @return array
 */
public function countFreeTiers() : array
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');
    $qb->select('COUNT(t.tierNumber)')
       ->where('t.tierNumber = :freeTier')
       ->groupBy('t.tierNumber')
       ->orderBy('t.tierNumber', 'ASC')
        ->setParameter('freeTier', Constants::FREE_TIER /* error here */)
       ->setParameter('true', true);

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Attempted to load class "Constants" from namespace "App".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

Am I not allowed to just use the "App" namespace?

Comment: When you say "root folder" do you mean under the src directory?

Comment: Hi Cerad, no it is outside the src directory.  Literally the root folder of the project.

Comment: Hi Cerad, I see what you are getting at.  Moving the Constants.php to inside the src folder fixed it.  Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need "public" identifier for const.

Comment: @revengeance As of 7.1, both public and private constants are supported.  So while I agree that public is redundant it does help to make things clear.

Comment: @Cerad Didn't actually know this, as I haven't yet migrated to 7.1, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is cerad's solution, not mine.

My problem was that my Constants.php was in the root folder of the project.

I had to move the Constants.php file to inside the src folder, so putting it at the root of src (as opposed to the root of the project) fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the class file into 'src/Utilities' and symfony will auto load it.